# Как сделать форму входа - поверх всех эллементов?

Tags: авторизация, dle

Установил шаблон на DLE но есть косяк, при нажатии на АВТОРИЗАЦИЯ, появляется окно АВТОРИЗАЦИИ но на мышку не реагиерует! Как я понял блок слева поверх него открыт и по этому наверное. Помогите решить этот вопрос, спасибо... [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот как я понял этот код отвечате за окно

```html
<script>function show_modal_dle() {$("#div_modal_dle").dialog({autoOpen: true,show: "fade",hide: "fade",width: 500,modal: true,});}</script>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: При нажатии на иконку, после чего всплывает окошко с авторизацией - не реагирует на нажатие мышкой. Будто сверху окна авторизации что то мешает нажать на поле Логин или пароль и на кнопку войти. То есть если кто то захочет войти, не войдет( Не знаю просто где капать. Сайт можно оставить, чтобы было проще понять мой вопрос?

Comment: Да, вы можете оставить адрес сайта.

Comment: mrfuntrash.site сайт. Хочу сделать форму входа и дальше уже буду заниматся ним